# Product in terms of $n$ of $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{7}{8} \cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{2n-1}{2n}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

What is the following product in terms of $n$?

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{7}{8} \cdot \cdots \cdot \frac{2n-1}{2n}$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{5}{6} \dotsb \frac{2n-1}{2n}=\frac{1\mathbf{2}3\mathbf{4}5 \dotsb (2n-1)\mathbf{2n}}{(2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \dotsb 2n)^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$$

Comment: Numerator should be $(2n)!$

Comment: I have edited it thanks.

Comment: The $2^{2n}$ should be $2^n$ - because there are only $n$ terms with $2$...

Comment: @johannesvalks But the denominator has a square.

Comment: Good catch - I was wrong about that!!!

Sorry about that... vote up!!!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative answer that has its uses, this product of fractions can be written as a definite integral:

$$\begin{align}
\frac12\frac34\frac56\frac78\dots\frac{2n-1}{2n}&=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$

Comment: This solution shows that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{2 k - 1}{2 k} = 0 $. As $ {\sin^{2 n}}(x) $ converges to $ 0 $ for all $ x \in \left[ 0,\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) $, and as $ |\sin^{2 n}| $ is dominated by $ 1 $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, it follows from the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem that
\begin{align}
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{2 k - 1}{2 k}
& = \lim_{n \to \infty}
    \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} {\sin^{2 n}}(x)
    ~ \mathrm{d}{x} \\
& = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi / 2} 0 ~ \mathrm{d}{x} \\
& = 0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Given

$$
(1/2)(3/4)(5/6)(7/8)\cdots([2n-1]/2n)
$$

Thus

$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{3}{4} \frac{5}{6} \cdots \frac{2n-1}{2n} = \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots [2n-1] \cdot 2n}{2^{2n} \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots 2n)^2 } = \frac{[2n]!}{2^n (n!)^2}
$$

Comment: you have inserted $2\cdot 4 \cdot $ in the numerator without dividing it.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks!