# Proof without induction of the inequalities related to product $\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, factorial, products

How do you prove the following without induction:

1)$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}>\frac{1}{2}$

2)$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

3)$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n2k-1<n^n$

I think AM-GM-HM inequality is the way, but am unable to proceed. Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: There is a proof of #2 without induction [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899857/mathematical-problem-induction/1899918#1899918). It is shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940425/prove-frac-1-2-cdot-frac-3-4-cdot-frac-5-6-cdots-frac2n-12n-frac) as well.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks, what about 1) and 2)?

Comment: Why don't you show what you have tried and exactly where you are stuck?

Comment: @StubbornAtom At first I was totally clueless when asked in exam, I thought about using the AM-GM-HMinequality, but the RHS dosent seem to yield in each case

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one). (OTOH maybe these ones are close enough to each other. It's basically a judgement call.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak All these have one theme:AM-GM inequality, hence the asking is highly appropriate-so I believe -what do you think?

Comment: First define $\prod_{k=1}^na_k$ without recursion. Then we can prove statements about it without induction.

Comment: I have tried to edit the title to make it [more informative](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question/589#589) (but still editing all three inequalities into the title seemed to be too much).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) For $k\ge2$,
$$
\frac{2k-1}{2k}\gt\frac12
$$
Therefore, for $n\ge2$
$$
\begin{align}
\left[\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right]^{1/n}
&=\left[\frac12\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}\right]^{1/n}\\
&\gt\left[\frac12\prod_{k=2}^n\frac12\right]^{1/n}\\
&=\left[\prod_{k=1}^n\frac12\right]^{1/n}\\[6pt]
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$

---

2) Squaring and cross-multiplication show that for $k\ge1$
$$
\frac{2k-1}{2k}\lt\sqrt{\frac{k-\frac12}{k+\frac12}}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}
&\lt\prod_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{k-\frac12}{k+\frac12}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\frac12}{n+\frac12}}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{2n+1}}
\end{align}
$$

---

3) The AM-GM says
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\right)^{\large\frac1n}
&\le\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\\[6pt]
&=n
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 8):

for problem $3$ notice that the arithmetic average of the numbers $1,3,5,7,\dots,2n-1$ is $n$, and they are also $n$ terms.

So we have $n > \sqrt[n]{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \dots (2n-1)}$ by AM-GM.

Raising to the $n$'th power yields the desired result.

Comment: You did 3, I did 1. What a team!

Comment: @martycohen Yeah, and $2$ is already in the comments, time for a well deserved break ! Good job partner.

Comment: thanks to the partners, by the way!

Comment: Nice, but how do you prove that the arithmetic mean of $1,3,\dots,2n-1$ is $n$ *without induction*?

Comment: @egreg: If $$S=1+3+\ldots+(2n-1)$$Then observe that $$S=(2n-1)+(2n-3)+\ldots+1$$Then you obtain, $2S=n\cdot 2n$ which gives you $S=n^2$.

Comment: @user170039 This uses induction as well. Every time you state something with $\dots$ in it, there's induction to use.

Comment: @egreg: Can you point out exactly where I have used induction? To what statement?

Comment: @egreg: Furthermore, if I interpret your question as asking for a formal proof of the formula $1+3+\ldots+(2n-1)=n^2$ then my proof is valid so long as you require that "the **formal proof** should be without induction (i.e., nowhere in the proof we will use the Induction Axiom)", it is because what my argument proves is the following meta-theorem (as opposed to a theorem) "For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have a deduction of the formula $1+3+\ldots+(2n-1)=n^2$ in $\sf{PA}$ without the Induction Axiom." Am I missing something?

Comment: @egreg Good point, although I think there is a difference between you proof being dependant on the well order principal AMD the proof actually being by induction.

Comment: And then there is the philosophical point that *any* statement which has "for all n" implies the use of induction in its proof.

Answer (score 6):

1) is equivalent to
$\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}>\frac{1}{2^n}
$
or
$2^n
>\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{2k-1}
$.

But
$\frac{2k}{2k-1}
=1+\frac{1}{2k-1}
\le 2
$
for $k \ge 1$
and
$\frac{2k}{2k-1}
=1+\frac{1}{2k-1}
\lt 2
$
for
$k \ge 2$
which makes this evident.

Comment: My edit was a typo jn the first inequality; RHS changed from $1/2^2$ to $1/2^n$

Answer (score 6):

Notice that in problem #$1$ if you raise each side to the $n$th power, then it is equivalent to showing that the product of the $n$ factors of the form

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\tag{1}$$

is greater than $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$. But that is clearly true since each factor in equation $(1)$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

You may notice that the product appearing in 1) and 2) is related to binomial coeffients. 
$$
\frac{1\cdot3\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdots(2n)}=
\frac{(2n)!}{(2\cdot4\cdots(2n))^2}=
\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)^2}=
\frac1{4^n} \binom{2n}n
$$
(See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842911/product-in-terms-of-n-of-frac12-cdot-frac34-cdot-frac56-cdo).)

So the inequalities in 1) and 2) are in fact equivalent to 
$$2^n < \binom{2n}n < \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{2n+1}}.$$

There already are several questions on this site about similar (or even stronger) inequalities for the [central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).

A sample of such questions (ordered by id)

- [Elementary central binomial coefficient estimates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/elementary-central-binomial-coefficient-estimates)
- [Prove that $2^n < \binom{2n}{n} < 2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448861/prove-that-2n-binom2nn-22n)
- [To prove the inequality:- $\frac{4^m}{2\sqrt{m}}\le\binom{2m}{m}\le\frac{4^m}{\sqrt{2m+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071253/to-prove-the-inequality-frac4m2-sqrtm-le-binom2mm-le-frac4m-s)

You can probably find more using [internal search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Binequality%5D+%22%5Cbinom%7B2n%7Dn%22), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%5Binequality%5D%20%22%5Cbinom%7B2n%7Dn%22%20site:math.stackexchange.com) or [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbinom%7B2n%7Dn%24%2C%20inequality&p=1). Or simply by checking the questions tagged [binomial-coefficients+inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients+inequality).

Comment: thanks, by the way, is it somehow related to erdös proof of bertrand's postulate?

Comment: An estimate on $\binom{2n}n$ is used in [Erdős' proof of Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand's_postulate) and some other proofs in number theory. However, I am not sure whether this one is used somewhere.